# How to hide/show/collapse/expand dynamically appended ul items?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css

Hello guys here is my data which I appended to `ul` with checkboxes as:

```
Id  name       subid   subname
1   India      1       Virat
1   India      2       Rohit
1   India      3       Shikar
2   Australia  4       Smith
2   Australia  5       warner
```

This forms a tree with checkboxes which are dynamically appended.

My data contains all these records separately. I grouped it and made as above.

```
var tree = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
    var groupName = data.d[i].name + "_" + data.d[i].id;
    if (!tree[groupName]) {
        tree[groupName] = [];
    }
    tree[groupName].push(data.d[i].subname + "_" + data.d[i].subid);
}

myArray = [];

for (var groupName in tree) {
    myArray.push({ team: groupName, player: tree[groupName] });
}

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var i1 = myArray[i].team;
    var parts = i1.split('_', 2);
    var name = parts[0];
    var id = parts[1];
    var myStringArray = myArray[i].player;

    $('.divclassid .multiselect-container').append($("<ul onclick='addnewClass();' class='collapselist' ><label class='checkbox'><input id='chk_" + id + "' class='chkCls' type='checkbox' onchange='chksubcls(this);'   value='" + id + "'/>" + name + "</label></ul>"));

    // debugger;
    if (myStringArray != "" + "_") {
        var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;

        for (var k = 0; k < arrayLength; k++) {
            var subidname = myStringArray[k];
            var subparts = subidname.split("_", 2);
            var subname = subparts[0];
            var subid = subparts[1];

            $('.divclassid .multiselect-container').append($("<ul onclick='addnewClass();' style='display:none;'  class='expandlist'><label class='checkbox subcls'  ><input id='chksub_" + id + "' class='chkClssub' type='checkbox'  value='" + subid + "'/>" + subname + "</label></ul>"))
        }
    }
}

function addnewClass() {
    $('.divclassid .btn-group').addClass('open');
}

function chksubcls(obj) {
    if ($('#chk_' + obj.value).prop('checked')) {
        // debugger;
        $('ul.expandlist').show();
        // Here, how to expand collapse only those which are checked?
    }
    else {
        // $('ul.expandlist').find('ul.chkClssub #chksub_' + obj.value).css('display', 'none');
        $('ul.expandlist').hide();
    }
}
```

Now I made my `ul` style `display: none`. When I check a checkbox, all the items are expanding. I need to expand only that team which is checked.

Suppose if `india` is checked, only

```
india
virat
rohit
shikar
```

should expand. It's not working. It is expanding the whole `ul` list. Please help.

I formed it as list with `ul`, which is dynamically appended with checkboxes.
Or is there any other way to add as tree, expand/collapse only checked. All the list is dynamically appended. On check of a checkbox, I am calling a function with this and I am passing the checked checkbox id. Now, how do I expand/collapse only checked team and players list?

When I am doing this, it's not working fine. All the list is expanded and collapsed on check of any team name. Only checked team name with players should be expanded. Everything is dynamically appended to a `div`.

Any other way to bind dynamically to `ul` with tree view and expand/collapse only selected will also help me.

Please help.

Comment: Please format your question properly next time. I see that you have already approved 5 edits despite having only 11 questions. Don't take edits for granted.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see btn-group div created into your code so inside addNewClass this line $('.divclassid .btn-group') won't do anything. Plus if you need to toggle the respective element. Write a listener on any element like `$('li').on('click',function(event) { $(event.target).toggle(); });` ( Just an example ) Hope this one works for you.

Comment: chksubcls() this function is called on click of a ul item. i have some ul items in the order of teams, i need to show only those teams which are selected, in the function chksubcls();